# Загрузка с зашифрованного диска с PXE

Tags: opensuse, lvm, защита, boot, linux

Господа!

Возникла задача, зашифровать полностью систему, и загружать ее с PXE.Система openSUSE 12.2, при установке указал зашифровать. initrd и vmlinuz отправил на pxe-сервер. При перезагрузке система спрашивает пароль для расшифровки раздела.

Как сделать так чтобы загрузка происходила без запроса пароля?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю используется cryptsetup ?

Если да, то почитайте в мане секцию  [Notes on Password Processing](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup)

Особенно интересно From stdin: Ну и в опции запуска cryptsetup добавить нужное.

Comment: А поподробнее? Где в загрузчике cryptsetup вызывается? Как передать параметры?

Comment: Посмотрите когда cryptsetup запускается, запускается он явно перед монтированием.

Comment: Не смог найти откуда и когда запускается... дайте подсказку ;)